# Custom textbox for date input

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I'm working on a WPF project that require to custom the textbox for user can input (NOT pick like datepicker) the date and the format is "YY\"年\"MM\"月\"DD\"日\"". Example: 16年09月21日. I have no idea how i can do that, please help me!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Masked TextBox.

Please see this link : [How to create a Masked textbox usnig WPF](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc112396-e8e9-41b7-97d1-e413850a59c9/how-to-create-a-masked-textbox-usnig-wpf?forum=wpf)

Comment: @AnjymSkhan thank you but my teacher doesn't want to use extended toolkit. Is there anyway to do it without using extended toolkit?